# remove unwanted colorseams on masked region in planetrack

Tags: tracking, masking

I mostly find solutions to my little blender problems by watching videos and reading tutorials. This time, I don't get it, so, hopefully someone can give me some hints on how to solve my problem:

I made a planetrack (cornerpin) video where a put some yellow letter on a blue building.
To make it look more realistic, there is a big lamp pole in the foreground, moving over my inserted  letters. I use a mask to mask out the pole, which works good.

The problem is: the pole has slight blue edge (halo) which is visible  when it moves over the yellow letters.

How do I remove this blue halo?

You can see it in the image below

Thanks for helping,
Michael
[image]

Comment: I think it likely has to do with the transparency falloff of the mask. I can't see your setup, so I don't know which mode (sequencer, compositing,, etc...) you're in, but wherever you have access to your Blend Mode, try changing it to alpha-clip and playing with the clip threshold. If you are using a node setup to apply the mask, try inserting a colorramp before  the  mask input to  get better control over the "tightness" of the mask.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: thanks for the ideas.  I used the node editor like this:  polemask -> dilate/erode(feather/-3/smooth) -> blur -> setalpha .   This gets overlayed over the videopart

Comment: sorry, I allways press 'return' to get a line break, which does send the comment. I will try the color ramp to adjust the mask. Where do I find this "alpha-clip"  you mentioned?

Comment: Ok, so you're in the compositor. I think it's the blur that's responsible for your problem (because it blurs the alpha cutoff). I understand why this can be necessary, but I also believe it is why you can see a "halo". The colorramp before the alpha input should still give you tighter control. Since it's a composite, I don't think blend mode applies here anyway.

Comment: yes, the blur is not good, or too much. I played with the settings and the problem is, the blue edge comes from the blue building in the background, which shines over the pole a little bit. So the edge of the pole is slighly blue in the video. If I make the mask smaller, it looks weird, since this make the pole smaller. If I make the mask big enough, one can see the blue color. Maybe I reduce the saturation of the pole color, so that the blue is not visible. A slight yellow shine would be good.  Maybe a 3d pole would help, as a last resort....